# Guzzle cannot send a web request to the same server?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, lumen, guzzle

Currently I'm making software in PHP which uses Guzzle to the same IP that it is hosted on to send a web request. At the moment, I'm making a request that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/temp/utils/transactions/callback?address=long_btc_address&balance=0&completed=0`
```

The code that should be returned should look like this

```php
$router->get('/temp/utils/transactions/callback', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($request, 'Callback');
   return 'yo';
});
```

Currently, the site is ran using:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Furthermore, the code that sends this request looks like this:

```php
$client = new Client();
$addy = decrypt($address->address);
$callback = $transaction->callback . "?address={$addy}&balance={$address->current_balance}&completed=0";
$res = $client->request('GET', $callback);
if ($res->getStatusCode() === 200) {
    return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

In summary, I'm not really sure how to solve this without a real-world test but I'd like to test it locally and see what I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `php -S`  as a single thread server.

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

So when `Guzzle` sends a request to the same server it causes what known as a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). The original request and the new request are both waiting for each other.

So because of that, you shouldn't make the script call itself. you should either use a real server that supports multi-threading, like Apache or Nginx.

Or the option I prefer: you can ask Laravel to call itself. something like:

```php
$req = Request::create($transaction->callback, 'GET',
    [
        'address' => $addy,
        'balance' => $address->current_balance,
        'completed' => 0,
    ]
);
$res = app()->handle($req); 

// deal with the response here...
```

Comment: Could I still use this method in an application in a production setting?

Comment: Yes, it'll be faster than guzzle anyway.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but would this also affect security in any way?

Comment: As far as I know NO it will not. It's just like using a guzzle client to send a request. it'll go through the middlewares, the router, the CSRF check,  cookie encryption ... etc. just like a normal request!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer IF the problem is solved, it'll benefit future people who'll see the question.

Comment: Of course @Majed DH an it works beautifully mate, thank you!

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work on public sites though, any ideas?

Comment: I've used it in my project and it's been in production for too long. Why wouldn't it work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm not sure. seems like it can request something on the same thread but any external sites say for example, Google.co.uk, it will produce an error.

Comment: This works only if you want to send yourself a request. if you want to send a request to another server or app you should use `guzzle`. My answer is specific if you want to call your app from within your app.